# dism The source files could not be found. Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files

Tags: .net, windows, windows-8, dism

I have installed a fresh copy of windows 8. Since, dot-net framework 3.5 is not installed in it. I used microsoft's **[dism tool](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dism/info)**  to enable this feature. I inserted windows 8 dvd and create a cmd file as follows

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:E:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

E: drive is my Windows 8 dvd drive. But i am getting an error 0x800f081f

[image: dism enable feature dot-net framework 3.5]

I have read many articles including https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3005628 but the update files given in this page are for windows 8.1 not for windows 8. 
 
I have also tried the command

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
dism /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
```

but none of these helped me out. Since it is a fresh window, so no windows updates are there to uninstall.

I wan to enable dotnet framework 3.5 in windows 8 using windows dvd or offline mode. Using dism command, i am getting this error

> Error: 0x800f081f The source files could not be found.Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature.

Comment: update to 8.1 (8 is out of support) and try here again to install .net 3.5 before installing any Windows updates. Also this question belongs to useruser.com

Comment: most of my clients still have windows 8. So there is no other options ?

Comment: again, Win8 is out of support and no longer gets any updates. To get new updates the users have to update to 8.1 (this is free for Win8 users) via the Windows Store.